# how to enable find window in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am using VS2008. The problem is when i want to open find window by both way(Ctrl-F or Edit-find or replace - Quick find) the window doesn't appear.

Can anyone tell me how to enable it??your help is most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reset the settings or restart it.
to reset use open command prompt then devenv /resetsettings

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot for your answer.But i have made the solution in other way. I have reset my settings following these steps...

To reset your settings

1.On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.

2.On the Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click Reset all settings and then click Next.

3.If you want to save your current settings combination, click Yes, save my current    settings, specify a file name, and then click Next.

—or—

If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and then click Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard.

4.In Which collection of settings do you want to reset to, select a settings collection from the list.

5.Click Finish.